# What is correct syntax to update SP multiperson column with array or string variable via rest api?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, ajax

Can't get the syntax right to update a SharePoint multiperson column.

some variables:

```
iArray // = array of multiple user ids
sArray = iArray.join(); // string of multiple user ids
json1 = "{'results': [" + iArray + "]}";
json2 = "{'results': [" + sArray + "]}";
```

hardcoding ids works:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
'From_x0020_ContactsId': {'results': [9,25]},
'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Lib_x005f_RFI2Item' }
}),
```

trying to pass an array or string, doesn't work:

```
'From_x0020_ContactsId': json1,
'From_x0020_ContactsId': json2,
'From_x0020_ContactsId': {'results': ["" + iArray + ""]},
'From_x0020_ContactsId': {'results': ["" + sArray + ""]},
'From_x0020_ContactsId': "{'results': [" + fIdArray.join() + "]}",
'From_x0020_ContactsId': {'__metadata': { 'type': 'Collection(Edm.Int32' }, 'results': iArray},
```

always primitive or Edm32 error. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As always, after struggling for hours on an issue then posting to StackExchange, I figure out the answer minutes later. I should have just passed the array as below, works for updating single or multiple users in this field:

```
'From_x0020_ContactsId': {'results': iArray},
```